# Detect WIFI connection in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I need to detect if the device my app is running on is currently connected to a WIFI network. I have read [the guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465399.aspx#adapt) I know i can determine the "connection cost" but i specifically want to know if there is a way to tell if the device is connected to WIFI or not.

Comment: I was hoping to use NetworkInterface class but it is a really limited version available for Windows Store Apps, all that remains is GetIsNetworkAvailable. WMI also seems to be disabled for Win Store Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype

now you can do something like this:

```
switch (internetConnectionProfile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType)
                {
                    case 71:
                        networkStatus = InternetAccess.WLAN;
                        break;

 ect....
```

Comment: This really makes me wonder why there isn't an enumeration for these magic numbers